# What is the difference between 困扰 and 问题 in 困扰人们很长时间的取球问题就这样被一个小孩子解决了?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

你瞧，困扰人们很长时间的取球问题就这样被一个小孩子解决了。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 13.

What is the difference between 困扰 and 问题? Why are they both needed here? Is 这样 referred to 困扰 or 问题? Isn't another one classifier as 样 needed here? One for 困扰 and one for 问题?

Or should 困扰 be considered verb?

困扰(perplexing / puzzling)人们(people)很长(very long)时间(time)的取(taking)球(ball)问题(problem)就这样(this one or this kind of or this "classifier")

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

困扰 means "something that bothers a person mentally", or puzzle; 问题 is "a question", or an "unsolved puzzle".

这样 = 如此, thus; in this way.

- 困扰人们很长时间的取球问题就这样被一个小孩子解决了。- The "how to take out the ball" puzzle/question, which had bothered/puzzled the people for a long time, thus was solved by the little kid. Or,
- The question/puzzle on "how to take out the ball", which had bothered/puzzled the people for a long time, was thus been solved by the little kid.

Again, note the difference between Chinese and English in the structure of the sentence. Also, I consider 困扰 is the "subject noun" in the former, but an "auxiliary verb" in the latter.

Answer (score 4):

困扰人们很长时间的取球问题就这样被一个小孩子解决了。

The problem with getting the ball out that has been perplexing people for a long time is thus solved by a child.

问题 is actually the subject and 困扰 is the verb. 取球问题 困扰 人们很长时间. In English, it is called a clause.

The main sentence is 取球问题 被 一个 小孩子 解决 了。

In many cases, we could have an article to lead the clause. For example,

这个(那个)困扰人们很长时间的取球问题就这样被一个小孩子解决了。

Answer (score 3):

“困扰” is considered a verb here.

I would translate it to: "look（你瞧）, the ball picking problem（取球问题）that (reversed 的, A that B = B的A）bothered people for a long time was solved by a child just like that（就这样被一个小孩子解决了）."